# Text-shadow keyframe-anim looking smooth in firefox but jumpy in webkit-browsers - why?

Tags: css, animation

yesterday i tried to animate text-shadows using keyframe animations.
the css looked something like this...

```
.sometxt{
-webkit-animation:shadow 5s linear 0s infinite alternate;
        animation:shadow 5s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes shadow {
0%{text-shadow:0px 0px green;}
100%{text-shadow:5px 0px green;}
}
@keyframes shadow {
0%{text-shadow:0px 0px green;}
100%{text-shadow:5px 0px green;}
}
```

(JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3yB8q/1/)

I kept previewing the page in firefox, where the animation looks great and runs fluid. looked at it chrome however, the whole thing looks like a stop-animation. taking the code above for example, every second the shadow JUMPS one pixel aside. while in firefox it is drawn as one smooth move.

How can I prevent this happening?

Comment: I suggest to use initials, without them looks english text really not good.

Comment: Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/3yB8q/ Looks like Webkit just doesn't draw shadows using sub pixel rendering – if you think about it, you are hoping that a shadow will be drawn at 0px, 0.1px, 0.2px etc – depending on how the browser works, it looks like it either decides thats impossible (Webkit), or does manage to do that (Gecko).